# How can I prevent Xcode from rebuilding sources shared between multiple targets?

Tags: xcode, build

I have an Xcode project with many targets, all of which depend on a core set of source files.

If I aggregate all of the targets and build the aggregate, then the shared source files get *rebuilt* for each target in the aggregate.

Is there any way to prevent this recompiling of the shared sources?

NOTE: I know I could make the shared sources into a static library and link to that from all of the targets, but I would prefer to avoid this.